# Can Azure Media Services be used to overlay a custom watermark that's different for each person?

Tags: azure, media-player, azure-media-services

We've been asked if we can help a client stream uploaded video files while overlaying a unique watermark per user, eg, their email address or username. Security on the stream needs to be good, but not necessarily ironclad. That is, enough to put someone off trying to grab the bits outside of the player (so some encryption is very helpful), while the overlay would hopefully make it clear that re-recording it, or saving the file, would help us track the perpetrator.

I was hoping some combo of Azure Media Services and the Azure Media Player might be able to do something like this, but for the life of me I can't find anything online about it.

We're not wedded to Azure if it's not possible using that service but is through an alternative.

Thanks so much for your help. It feels like this shouldn't be a unique request, but I can't find anything on Google. Maybe my search terms are letting me down.

Comment: Media Services does not currently offer what is known as ‘forensic’ watermarking. _([source](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/21/advanced-encoding-features-in-azure-media-encoder/))_

Comment: Thanks @mmeverdies. Do you know of any other video service that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends if you are trying to do server side watermarking or client side watermarking. Currently Azure Media Services doesn't have support for server side watermarking.

However, this is easily achieved on the client side with Azure Media Player -> because the player uses HTML elements, you can easily add an additional HTML element for your overlay and style it with CSS to display the required information.